# InvalidUseOfMatchersException: Invalid use of argument matchers

Tags: testing, mockito

I am new with testing. I have tried this but got an exception.

```
@Mock
private Context context;    
...
when(service.getResult(any(), context)).thenReturn(new ArrayList<>());
```

Exception:

> org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.InvalidUseOfMatchersException:
>   Invalid use of argument matchers!
>   2 matchers expected, 1 recorded:

Answer (score 9):

`Mockito.any()` is a Mockito argument matcher. As you specify it in one of the parameters defined in a mock recording, you have to use argument matcher for all parameters.
`Mockito.eq(T)` is the way to transform any parameter into a argument matcher.
So this should be fine :

```
@Mock
private Context context;    

@Mock
private Service service; 
...
when(service.getResult(any(), eq(context)).thenReturn(new ArrayList<>());
```

Comment: Probably a duplicate, but a nice precise answer. So who am I to worry :-)

Comment: And well, nobody beats Jon Skeet. He occasionally allows us to think that to encourage us!

Comment: @GhostCast I like well your theory on the kindness of Jon toward us :)

Comment: I probably only saw .05 % of all the content he put up here, but I think he is one of the most "nice guys" I ever saw on online boards. A role model on many levels.

Comment: I called you : GhostCast ! Sorry :) I agree totally about Jon. A very very nice person. Long life to him !

Answer (score 1):

Similar question has been asked many times. I think the best answer is here:

> Mockito requires you to either use only raw values or only matchers when stubbing a method call. The full exception (not posted by you here) surely explains everything.

[Invalid use of argument matchers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24468456/invalid-use-of-argument-matchers/24468549)