# Error when trying to mock an exception in Java

Tags: java, junit

I'm trying to mock an exception and then returning it. But i'm having this error which i have no idea:

> type="org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.InvalidUseOfMatchersException"
> org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.InvalidUseOfMatchersException:
> Invalid use of argument matchers! 2 matchers expected, 4 recorded

My code is:

```
TitanException e = Mockito.mock(TitanException.class);

long bankId = 111L, productId = 220L, subproductId = 333L;

icctr009.execute(bankId, productId, subproductId);
    
when(icctr009.titanQueryForListMap(anyString(), anyString(), anyString(), anyMap()))
      .thenThrow(e);
```

Comment: Does https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16458136/mockito-invalid-use-of-argument-matchers answer your question?

Comment: @Reporter Sorry, but i dont understand yet

Comment: Have you read this question?

Comment: Yes,  i have tried     when(icctr009.titanQueryForListMap(Mockito.anyString(), Mockito.anyString(), Mockito.anyString(), Mockito.anyMap()))
       .thenThrow(e);
     but its not working

Comment: can you show your titanQueryForListMap method?

Comment: Error says you may not required 4 arguments here in `icctr009.titanQueryForListMap` function. Please show how cctr009.titanQueryForListMap looks like.